# How accurate is POSIT estimation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Consider I have a imaging system of X-ray, the image has no distortion and the resolution of the image obtained is of 2048*2048

1)  How accurate will the POSIT algorithm provide me when i estimate with respect to a defined object?

2) Would comparing two different POSIT values(by changing the orientation of defined object) with respect to one other gives me a measure of POSE error in rotational and translational values respective to the object?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "no distortion" you mean that the source is well approximate as a point one.

The accuracy will be limited by how well you can detect and match point features on the object (or rather, "in" the object, as your images are integrals of opacity), and by how well separated in depth the feature themselves are.

Comment: I want to know how accurate changes can it give interms of number? or what is the smallest measurement it can measure?? if my pixels have a distance spacing value of 200 microns each.

Comment: Hard to tell without a complete description of the setup. Sounds like you may need (or wish) to design a calibration procedure using one or more well-known manufactured 3d jig or jigs. From experience, calibrated setups tend to become expensive and complex rather quickly - I recommend thinking long and hard about what the accuracy requirement for your ultimate product is, before going down that rabbit hole.